# Random/Inconsistent Code Run Times - Parallel HPC

Tags: debugging, parallel-processing, fortran, slurm, intel-fortran

I've been running some tests on an HPC. I have a code and if it's executed in serial, the run times are completely consistent. This wasn't always the case, but I included commands in my batch files so that it reserves an entire node and all its memory. Doing this allowed for almost perfectly consistent code execution times.

However, now that I am doing small scale parallel tests, the code execution times seem random. I would expect there to be some variation now that parallelization has been introduced, but the scale of randomness seems quite bizarre.

No other jobs are performed on the node so it should be fine - when in serial it is very consistent, so it must be something to do with the parallelization.

Does anyone know what could cause this? I've included a graph showing the execution times - there is a pretty clear average, but also major outliers. All results produced are identical and correct.

I'm under an NDA so cannot include much info about my code. Please feel free to ask questions and I'll see if I can help. Apologies if I'm not allowed to answer!

I'm using Fortran 90 as the main code language, and the HPC uses Slurm. NTASKS = 8 for these tests, however the randomness is there if NTASKS > 1. Number of tasks and randomness don't seem particularly linked, except if it is in parallel then the randomness occurs. I'm using Intel's autoparallelization feature, rather than OpenMP/MPI.

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Is anybody else using the cluster? Does your code do significant amounts of I/O? Are processes/threads bound to cores? Is the placement of the threads/processes within the node consistent for all runs?

Comment: Is the paralleisation bug-free and deterministic?

Comment: Since you are using automatic parallelization, I think the tag for the actual compiler isvery important.

Comment: Yeah the HPC is busy - I often have long queuing times. The run times that I have here are produced in the code itself though. Right at the start a file is made, and another is made right at the end. I did this rather than relying on HPC data, which occasionally was inacurate. 

Not much I/O - code is just one source code (with subroutines). All inputs are part of the code, results outputs are simple text files. All txt results are identical (nearly!). 

Relatively new to HPC's so not sure of the rest - I just include NTASKS = 8 in batchfile. I let the autoparallelization do the rest.

Comment: ifort -parallel -qopt-report-phase=par -r8 -fpp -mcmodel=medium -o XX XX.f90

This is the the compile command in the batch file. All tests used exactly the same batchfile commands. (I just removed actual name of source code for NDA reasons )

Comment: So there's a blank 'start' file generation right at the beginning of the code. The code does the computations, produces the results at given time step intervals, then outputs some terminal prints of certain data values. Right before the code finishes literally everything, there is an 'end' file generation, which is also blank. I use a time calculator to find the difference in the start and stop files to get the exact code times. This isn't very elegant but it works well and I used that method when getting the perfectly consistent serial timings.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning as well that I also do check the HPC run time data too - it's almost always in agreement with the start/stop timings, but occasionally it's inaccurate if there's very long queuing times, so I've stuck with the start/stop timings for the graphs I made.

Comment: Try to time only the computation. Ignore any file I/O.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!! Thanks for your help everyone!

I did small scale tests 100 times to get to the root of the problem.

As the execution times were rather small, I noticed that the larger outliers (longer run times) often occurred when a lot of new jobs from other users were submitted to the HPC. This made a lot of sense and wasn't particularly surprising.

The main reason these results really confused me was because of the smaller outliers (much quicker run times). It made sense that sometimes it would take longer to run if it was busy, but I just couldn't figure out how sometimes it ran much quicker, but still giving the same results!

Probably a bit of a rookie error, but it turns out not all nodes are equal on our HPC! About 80% of the nodes are identical, giving roughly the same run times (or longer if busy). BUT, the newest 20% (i.e. the highest node numbers with Node0XX) must be higher performance.

I checked the 'sacct' Slurm data and job run times, and can confirm all faster execution time outliers occurred on these newer nodes.

Very odd situation and something I hadn't been made aware of. Hopefully this might be able to help someone out if they're in a similar situation. I spent so long checking source codes/batchfiles/code timings that I hadn't even considered the HPC hardware itself. Something to keep in mind.

I did much longer (about an hour) tests and the longer execution time outliers didn't really exist (because the small queuing penalty was now relatively small in comparison to total execution time). But, the much quicker execution time outliers still occurred. Again, I checked the account data and these outliers always occurred on the high node numbers.

Hopefully this can help at least one person with a similar headache.

Cheers!

[image: Small scale tests]